# In the japanese The legend of Zelda (e.g. Ocarina of Time), why is navi spelled ナビィ and not just ナビ?

Tags: words, katakana

I started playing the Japanese version of Ocarina of time and noticed that navi is spelled as ナビィ instead of just ナビ. I know that you can combine e.g. フ and イ　for フィ, but the one in ナビィ seems redundant.

Comment: This is not really a problem. It's a name of a fairy, so Nintendo could have named her even completely differently in both versions. For example, チンクル is Tingle in English, not Chinkle or Tinkle or something, but no one cares. That said, the followings are my speculation of how she was named. In English, the common shortening of "navigator" is "nav." By adding "i", "navi" sounds already fairly unique as a name of a character. On the other hand, the natural shortened form of "ナビゲーター" is "ナビ" in Japanese, so the developers had to add extra "ィ" at the end to make the name sound more unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I'm right, but my guess with this is that it just makes the name seem more *unique*. The Zelda universe is full of unusual names, and this might be a shortcut in Japanese to indicate a slightly more exotic name given the limitations of the syllabic writing system. If I see ナビィ instead of ナビ it makes me think that the "i" sound should be inflected in some non-standard way, even if the characters themselves don't specify exactly which way. In Okinawa, for example, ナビィ is the word for 鍋{なべ}. I can't find a pronunciation guide for it, but the fact that it's used for Okinawa-ben alone should be enough of an indication of what the effect is, I hope.