# Why does this store named サァラ have a small ァ in the name?

Tags: pronunciation, katakana

Over on [this awesome answer about old and unused katakana forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15120/119), I notice that among the examples is the word "valve", written as `ヷァルブ`. It has a small `ァ` character in addition to the `ヷ` that precedes it. What puzzles me is that I can't imagine how `ヷァルブ` would be pronounced any differently than `ヷルブ`. Maybe the small `ァ` does the same thing as `ー`, but then why not write it as `ヷールブ`? Also, I'm no expert on katakanization of English, but I wouldn't think extending the vowel sound in "valve" would be the right way to convert it.

`ヷァルブ` might be an archaic way of writing "valve" that is no longer in use, but it reminded me of a store I pass by on my bike now and again, called [`サァラ麻布{あざぶ}`](http://www.sala-azabu.co.jp/). I've never been interested in the furniture they sell, but the name has always caught my attention. They write the English version of their name as "[Sala Azabu](http://www.sala-azabu.co.jp/index_e.html)". If I had seen the English first and someone asked me to write it in katakana, I'd have simply gone with `サラ`.

What is the small `ァ` character doing in these instances? How is `サァ` pronounced differently from `サー` or `サ`?

Comment: A humble side note from a newby:) I'd been searching for katakana charts that covers sounds of foreing words; in them, I often see the phoneme `/v/` written in katakana as `ヴ` (an _u_ with dakuten) often followed by a small vowel to complete a sillabe (va:ヴァ vi:ヴィ vu:ヴ ve:ヴェ vo:ヴォ). So, I would expect to see _valve_ written as `ヴァルヴ`, which I think would sound nearer to the English pronunctiation `/vælv/`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the japanese The legend of Zelda (e.g. Ocarina of Time), why is navi spelled ナビィ and not just ナビ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/in-the-japanese-the-legend-of-zelda-e-g-ocarina-of-time-why-is-navi-spelled)

Comment: @Roimer You're right, but notice that the spelling Dave used in his post is ヷァルブ - that's not a ヴ, but rather ヷ: a katakana わ with dakuten (which is not conventional - it confused me, too). Presumably ヷ is already /va/, so ヷァ should then be /vaː/, hence Dave's question - why ヷァ rather than ヷー?

Comment: @senshin my bad, I should have clarified my comment. What I really meant was "So, I would expect to see valve written as `ヴァルヴ` _rather than_ `ヷァルブ`". Any way, Dave's questions about why to use `ァ` in `サァ` (and in `ヷァ`) is still interesting.

Comment: @Kaji, if it's a duplicate, then why is the answer on that other question completely different? Also, note that if the answer here is right, then the accepted answer there, that it does not change the mora but only makes the name "unique", is potentially incorrect.

Comment: It's possible that the answer on the other is off or incomplete; I have my own answer that I retracted on that question as well.  I was merely suggesting the duplicate based on the fact that the apparent question in the titles of both appeared to be the same thing, just with ィ in one and ァ in the other.

Comment: Long story short: Maybe we need Tsuyoshi or Chocolate to weigh in and give a native perspective the issue?

Comment: @Kaji - Chocolate and Tsuyoshi, and other native speakers on JLU, are excellent resources, and it would be great to have them provide answers. Not because they are native speakers, though, but because they are effective teachers. I'm a native speaker of English, but I know next to nothing about it's grammatical structures or how a ESL student learns effectively. Basically, native ≠ expert.

Comment: @DaveMG: I think we're moving towards a state of "violent agreement", as I've heard it called before.  Agreed that native != expert, but when a native is also an expert it allows for a greater degree of clarity than a non-native expert at times.  That's all I was trying to convey.

Comment: @Kaji - fair enough. `:)`. "Violently" agreed. `;)`

Comment: @DaveMG: Glad you like my post, BTW!  That said, I did a bit of re-reading on it and noticed a small error on my part that seems to have contributed to this.  ヷルブ is indeed correct; I accidentally left the ァ in on that one when changing from ヴァ to ヷ.  I've updated the other post to fix this mistake, but I'll let you update your question as you feel is best appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

#### On the pronunciation

サ has a length of 1 mora, サァ and サー are both 2 mora.

> 前の音があ段の音の場合は、長音と同じように扱う。
>   If an A-row sound precedes it, ァ is treated just like ー.

#### On the usage

Usually used in foreign words.

> 主に外来語や方言において使用される。
>   Mainly used in foreign or dialectal words.

#### Source

http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%81

See also http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D

Comment: Thank you for this response. I think it might be technically accurate. However, what makes me unclear is that using three mora to express "Sala" in katakana strikes me as odd. "Sala" looks like two mora to me. Are we totally sure the store, and possibly other similar instances, are not going for some other effect?

Comment: "Sala" is indeed two syllables but not necessarily two mora depending on how the stress accent is put.